# How do I show the dependents of a package?

Tags: homebrew

I would like to know why a specific package is installed so I would like to get a list of the installed dependents.

Comment: @icondaemon I rolled back the edit. From what I understand, the OP wants to see which package required package X to get installed (and not the list of packages which package X depends on).

Answer (score 1):

For treeview of all packages and their dependencies:

```
brew deps --tree --installed
```

For specific package (in this case Rust):

```
brew deps --tree --installed rust
```